# Schema error on JDBC Sink using ByteArrayConverter for key and value

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm trying to setup a simple JDBC PostgreSQL sink to copy data from one Kafka topic to my PostgreSQL instance.

I would like to simply copy bytes from one Kafka topic to one Postgres table. There should be no data conversion involved.

I'm using these converters:

```
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.converters.ByteArrayConverter
```

The error message is very strange to me:

`Sink connector 'MY_CONNECTOR' is configured with 'delete.enabled=false' and 'pk.mode=none' and therefore requires records with a non-null Struct value and non-null Struct schema, but found record at (topic='MY_TOPIC',partition=0,offset=664253924,timestamp=1602894844052) with a byte[] value and bytes value schema.`

What could be the issue? Why is it asking for schema if there are only bytes involved?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The sink doesn't know how to unpack the byte array into your table columns.

Therefore you would need a Struct with named fields, and within you could assign bytearray values, assuming the column types are BLOB

Unclear if you need both the key and the value in the database, but easiest way to create a struct post-ByteArrayConverter would be to hoist it

```
"transforms": "HoistField",
"transforms.HoistField.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.HoistField$Value",
"transforms.HoistField.field": "_c0"
```

Change `_c0` to your actual database column name